# Is it possible to log a bug report for JDK 5?

Tags: java, java-5, bug-reporting

I would like to log a bug report for JDK 5.

This page 
http://bugs.java.com/

points to 
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

that has options to log only JDK 7 and JDK 8 bugs.

Although JDK is nearing (or has reached) EOL,

I would still like to go ahead and log it so as to benefit those who are still using it.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Java5 reached EOL in October 2009.

Comment: Even Java6 has reached EOL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question that Oracle can best answer (to it's enterprise customers).  For more refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: @devnull I am looking for any options for non-enterprise users. Hence the question. I do remember coming across the above page before. Thanks though.

Comment: If you ran across the page earlier, then you'd realize that the public support for v5 ended quite some time back.  And as you noticed, the bug reporting site doesn't provide the option of reporting bugs against the said version!

Comment: My thoughts were that even if bugs were not being fixed, a place for reporting them would be available. This way those who are still on 1.5 would have a good reason to move on at-least because of that. Otherwise they would still be on 1.5 thinking 'i don't need those additional features'

Comment: @devnull Created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440958/which-oracle-products-use-jdk-1-5-hotspot-vm

Comment: Created a new site on Area 51 with the question I wanted to ask in the first place. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66412/open-and-newly-discovered-bugs-in-eold-software/66414#66414

Answer (score 2):

The java version is no longer supported:

```
    The End Of Public Updates (Formerly called End Of Life -> EOL) dates are:

    J2SE 1.4   -  Oct 2008
 --->   J2SE 5.0   -  Oct 2009
    Java SE 6  -  Feb 2013
    Java SE 7  -  Mar 2015
```

This meens it is no longer supported.

NB: If you are still using 1.5 for your program, you need to think to update because 1.8 official release is in 2 days! Your are far behind!

So in conclusion, it is completely useless to post a 1.5 bug.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a lots of java 5 bugs:

https://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&start=1&group=bugs.sun.com&q=java+5

In the book:
http://www.horstmann.com/corejava/bugs5.html#CJ5V1
http://www.horstmann.com/corejava/bugs5.html#CJ5V2